# Move Users in PowerShell to another OU without CSV

Tags: powershell, active-directory, move

Is there a command that lets me move anyone and everyone in a given OU to another OU within the same domain?
Here's the trick: do it without knowing how many users there are in the origin OU, without knowing their account names or any details about them.  And do it without a .CSV file.

I've tried running:

```
    Get-ADUser * -Properties NTAccountName -SearchBase "OU=Symphony,OU=Users,DC=HSP,DC=HSPHealth,DC=org"
```

But PowerShell does not care for the * where I have it.  Basically, I want to take any and all users that are currently in "HSPHealth/HSP/Users/Symphony" OU and move them to a different OU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want `Get-ADUser -Filter * ...`.  The command defaults to the `-Identity` parameter for the first unnamed parameter.  You were looking for a user *named* `*`.

Comment: That worked.  I get access denied for the move.  But I'm willing to bet that just means I need a domain admin to look at my account and give me privileges.  Thanks for the quick answer, Bacon!

Comment: @TrevorRousseau Probably.  Try `Move-ADObject` with the `-WhatIf` parameter to see what it would try to do without having the complete permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You are after the Move-ADObject cmdlet:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/move-adobject